# Assigning Values to List items in Several Related Lists

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have three lists: "products", "prices" and "item numbers".
When user input is added to these lists, how do I, for example, make Python create an association between, let's say "product 6, price 6 and item number 6"?

What I want to be able to see is when user chooses an item number from the table, it is stored and the item number actually knows to assign itself the value of the product and the price.

```
Jay's House of Rip-Offs


Item Number     |Item Name       |Price           
--------------------------------------------------
1               |Notebook        |4.99            
2               |Atari           |99.99           
3               |TrapperKeeper   |89.99           
4               |Jeans           |3.99            
5               |Insects         |2.99            
6               |Harbormaster    |299.99          
7               |Lobotomy        |19.99           
8               |PunkRock        |3.99            
9               |HorseFeathers   |4.99            
10              |Pants           |2.99            
11              |Plants          |119.99          
12              |Salami          |1.99            

Order products [Y / N]?:
```

Here is the code I have, and I don't really know what to do to make it work. I need the input from user to store in 'orders' and 'quantity'. Also, the input from the name and address inputs needs to be stored in the respective list above.

```
products = ['Notebook', 'Atari', 'TrapperKeeper', 'Jeans', 'Insects', 
'Harbormaster', 'Lobotomy', 'PunkRock', 'HorseFeathers', 'Pants', 
'Plants', 'Salami']
prices = ['4.99', '99.99', '89.99', '3.99', '2.99', '299.99', '19.99', 
'3.99', '4.99', '2.99', '119.99', '1.99']
item_nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ,9, 10, 11, 12]
orders = []
quantity = []
response = ''
cust_name = ''
street = ''
city = ''
state = ''
zipcode = 0
order_total = 0
order_summary = ''

print("Jay's House of Rip-Offs\n\n")
titles = ('Item Number', 'Item Name', 'Price')
data = [titles] + list(zip(item_nums, products, prices))

for i, d in enumerate(data):
    line = '|'.join(str(x).ljust(16) for x in d)
    print(line)
    if i == 0:
        print('-' * len(line))

while str(input("Order products [Y / N]?: ")) != 'N':
    item_nums = input("Enter an item number: ")
    orders.append(item_nums)
    quantity = input("How many? ")

    if len(item_nums) == 0:
        print("Thank you for browsing.")
    else:
        cust_name = input("Enter name: ")
        street = input("Enter street address: ")
        city = input("Enter city or town name: ")
        state = input("Enter state or province: ")
        zipcode = input("Enter zipcode: ")
```

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're asking exactly, but I think you want to use a `class` instead of three separate lists: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html

Comment: ohhh okay. we JUST started learning about classes in class. that's all a giant mystery sea of tossing underscores and code to me, yet.

Comment: This is just a table. For an object oriented approach create an Item class, but you may also be interested in simpler approaches like using a dict with item number as key and tuples or lists (if mutable) as values, or named tuples (tuples like records with named fields) if data is imutable

Comment: however, the part i'm dealing with currently is something i've been working on well before we started learning about classes. 
Three Lists: each position should correspond with the position in the other two lists. i'll check out classes a little bit deeper, but I'm sure there's a way to do it without them, so that when i get to the actual calculation part of the program, the item number and quantity input by the user will finger the right price and item.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a class how about using nested dictionaries to store your data? A possible implementation could look like this:

```
products = {1: {"Type": "Notebook", "Price": 4.99}, 2: {"Type": 
"Atari", "Price": 99.99}} 

print(products[1]) 

> {'Type': 'Notebook', 'Price': 4.99}
```